# Angular 17 SSR - No tasks executed on server

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-ssr

Recently, I updated an Angular project from version 16 to version 17. Today, I decided to add SSR to the project. The project is running with no problems when served using npm run dev:ssr, and the HTML is being rendered on the server side, but no logic written in TypeScript is being executed on server at all, and I need some things to be executed on server.

For example, this is the constructor of my AppComponent:

```
    constructor(
```

> Blockquote

```
    private _router: Router,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
 console.log(isPlatformServer(this.platformId) ? 'Server' : 'Client'); 

}
```

And it is always being executed in browser for some reason, but I need to write some code that's gonna be executed on server first. I think my project might be improperly configured, but I'm not sure where to find the solution.

Further info about the project:

1. It contains 4 Lazy Loaded modules (if this is relevant);
2. Here's my AppServerModule code:

   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';

   ```
    import { AppModule } from './app.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

    import { FlexLayoutServerModule } from '@ngbracket/ngx-layout/server';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule,
        ServerModule,
        FlexLayoutServerModule,
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    })
    export class AppServerModule {}
   ```
3. Here's my server.ts:

```
  
    import 'zone.js/node';
    
    import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
    import { CommonEngine } from '@angular/ssr';
    import * as express from 'express';
    import { existsSync } from 'node:fs';
    import { join } from 'node:path';
    import AppServerModule from './src/main.server';
    
    // The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
    export function app(): express.Express {
      const server = express();
      const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/KempaWebApp/browser');
      const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html'))
        ? join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')
        : join(distFolder, 'index.html');
    
      const commonEngine = new CommonEngine();
    
      server.set('view engine', 'html');
      server.set('views', distFolder);
    
      // Example Express Rest API endpoints
      // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
      // Serve static files from /browser
      server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
        maxAge: '1y'
      }));
    
      // All regular routes use the Angular engine
      server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
        const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;
    
        commonEngine
          .render({
            bootstrap: AppServerModule,
            documentFilePath: indexHtml,
            url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
            publicPath: distFolder,
            providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl }],
          })
          .then((html) => res.send(html))
          .catch((err) => next(err));
      });
    
      return server;
    }
    
    function run(): void {
      const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;
    
      // Start up the Node server
      const server = app();
      server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
      });
    }
    
    // Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
    // '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
    // The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
    declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
    const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
    const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
    if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
      run();
    }
    
    export default AppServerModule;
```

3. This is what I have in main.server.ts:

`export { AppServerModule as default } from './app/app.module.server'`;

If there's any other relevant info I can provide, please, ask me in the comment.

**UPDATE:**
Here's my angular.json:

```
    {
    
          "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
          "version": 1,
          "newProjectRoot": "projects",
          "projects": {
            "AuroraWebApp": {
              "projectType": "application",
              "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                  "style": "scss"
                },
                "@schematics/angular:application": {
                  "strict": false
                }
              },
              "root": "",
              "sourceRoot": "src",
              "prefix": "app",
              "architect": {
                "build": {
                  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                  "options": {
                    "outputPath": "dist/AuroraWebApp/browser",
                    "index": "src/index.html",
                    "main": "src/main.ts",
                    "polyfills": [
                      "zone.js"
                    ],
                    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                    "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
                    "assets": [
                      "src/favicon.ico",
                      "src/assets",
                      "src/robots.txt",
                      "src/sitemap.xml"
                    ],
                    "styles": [
                      "src/styles.scss"
                    ],
                    "scripts": []
                  },
                  "configurations": {
                    "production": {
                      "budgets": [
                        {
                          "type": "initial",
                          "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                          "maximumError": "2mb"
                        },
                        {
                          "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                          "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                          "maximumError": "10kb"
                        }
                      ],
                      "index": {
                        "input": "src/index.prod.html",
                        "output": "index.html"
                      },
                      "fileReplacements": [
                        {
                          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                          "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                        }
                      ],
                      "outputHashing": "all"
                    },
                    "staging": {
                      "budgets": [
                        {
                          "type": "initial",
                          "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                          "maximumError": "2mb"
                        },
                        {
                          "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                          "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                          "maximumError": "10kb"
                        }
                      ],
                      "fileReplacements": [
                        {
                          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                          "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                        }
                      ],
                      "outputHashing": "all"
                    },
                    "development": {
                      "buildOptimizer": false,
                      "optimization": false,
                      "vendorChunk": true,
                      "extractLicenses": false,
                      "sourceMap": true,
                      "namedChunks": true
                    }
                  },
                  "defaultConfiguration": "production"
                },
                "serve": {
                  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                  "configurations": {
                    "production": {
                      "buildTarget": "AuroraWebApp:build:production"
                    },
                    "development": {
                      "buildTarget": "AuroraWebApp:build:development"
                    }
                  },
                  "defaultConfiguration": "development"
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                  "options": {
                    "buildTarget": "AuroraWebApp:build"
                  }
                },
                "test": {
                  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                  "options": {
                    "polyfills": [
                      "zone.js",
                      "zone.js/testing"
                    ],
                    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                    "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
                    "assets": [
                      "src/favicon.ico",
                      "src/assets",
                      "src/robots.txt",
                      "src/sitemap.xml"
                    ],
                    "styles": [
                      "src/styles.scss"
                    ],
                    "scripts": []
                  }
                },
                "server": {
                  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
                  "options": {
                    "outputPath": "dist/AuroraWebApp/server",
                    "main": "server.ts",
                    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
                    "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss"
                  },
                  "configurations": {
                    "production": {
                      "outputHashing": "media",
                      "fileReplacements": [
                        {
                          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                          "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "staging": {
                      "outputHashing": "media",
                      "fileReplacements": [
                        {
                          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                          "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "development": {
                      "buildOptimizer": false,
                      "optimization": false,
                      "sourceMap": true,
                      "extractLicenses": false,
                      "vendorChunk": true
                    }
                  },
                  "defaultConfiguration": "production"
                },
                "serve-ssr": {
                  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ssr-dev-server",
                  "configurations": {
                    "development": {
                      "browserTarget": "AuroraWebApp:build:development",
                      "serverTarget": "AuroraWebApp:server:development"
                    },
                    "production": {
                      "browserTarget": "AuroraWebApp:build:production",
                      "serverTarget": "AuroraWebApp:server:production"
                    }
                  },
                  "defaultConfiguration": "development"
                },
                "prerender": {
                  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:prerender",
                  "options": {
                    "routes": [
                      "/"
                    ]
                  },
                  "configurations": {
                    "production": {
                      "browserTarget": "AuroraWebApp:build:production",
                      "serverTarget": "AuroraWebApp:server:production"
                    },
                    "development": {
                      "browserTarget": "AuroraWebApp:build:development",
                      "serverTarget": "AuroraWebApp:server:development"
                    }
                  },
                  "defaultConfiguration": "production"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "cli": {
            "cache": {
              "enabled": false
            },
            "analytics": false
          }
        }
```

Comment: How exactly do you know it does not run on the server?

Comment: As I said, my HTML is being rendered on server, but when I perform following in my AppComponent's constructor: 

console.log(isPlatformServer(this.platformId) ? 'Server' : 'Client'); 

I'm always getting 'Client' as a result. And it's the only line of code I have in my AppComponent's constructor.

Comment: You always get 'Client' in the browser because console.log is always run, the condition only determines what to show, so most likely you also see 'Server' in your server console, at least that is how the newly generated A17 ssr project behaves.

Comment: Actually, I don't see anything in my server console.

Comment: Ok, then it would be nice to see other related configurations, like angular.json, main.server.ts, and so on, or you could provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I've just provided angular.json in update of the question. main.server.ts is already in the question, it's just one line of code.  And I'm not able to provide a minimal reproducable example since the project is quite large, and it will require a lot of editing for me to provide a minimal reproducable example.

Comment: In v17 new builders are used for ssr, there are no separate targets for server and client and it seems that your angular.json is not updated for all these changes. Take a look at [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/esbuild#using-the-application-builder)